# Regular Expression to replace " {" with "(newline){" in xcode

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode

I need to change my coding style of putting opening braces in same line to new line. I need to find and replace the (space){ with (newline){. I heard using regular expression find and replace, its pretty simple.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Does the standard newline thing work? (`\n`)

Comment: Be careful when `{` occurs inside a string-, or char-literal. Most IDE's have some sort of format-templates you can adjust and then re-factor/re-format your code base, perhaps Xcode has that as well? It's tricky to go search-and-replace manually.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You could try the following:

- In the Find box, type <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>{</kbd> <kbd>$</kbd>
- In the Replace box, type <kbd>control+q</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd> <kbd>{</kbd>

<kbd>control+q</kbd> is needed to quote the return key. There’s no visual feedback for typing <kbd>control+q</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd>, so the only visible character in the replace box is the opening curly brace:

[image: Screenshot Find & Replace]

Although this answers your question, there’s (at least!) one problem: it won’t indent the opening curly brace, so something like

```
- (void)method {
    for (obj in collection) {
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    }
}
```

is converted to

```
- (void)method
{
    for (obj in collection)
{
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    }
}
```

The menu item Edit > Format > Re-Indent will place the opening curly braces in the correct indentation tab but there might be non-desired side effects to your code style.

---

**Edit:** as commented in the other answer, you might want a regular expression that matches an arbitrary number of whitespaces surrounding the curly brace, e.g. \s*{\s*$

Comment: can you please tell what needs to be entered as pure texts??

Comment: @Aaron What do you mean by pure texts?

Comment: @Bavarious I mean what I have to type in the search and replace box. For eg: \s\{$ . I didn't understand what you have asked me to enter in the replace box.

Comment: @Aaron In the replace box, you need to type control+Q, i.e., type control and hold down the control key, type Q, and then release the control key. After that, type return. After that, type {. You need to type control+Q so that Xcode accepts the return key as a newline in the replacement string — \n, as suggested by others, doesn’t work.

Comment: @Aaron e.g. means for example.

Comment: @Bavarious When I type Q by pressing control key, nothing is coming. Also when I replace it some inverted ? comes. Still not able to solve the issue.

Comment: @Aaron control+q is not a visible character. It is a ‘special’ character used to indicate that the next character (in your case, return) is interpreted differently. I have no idea why you’re getting ¿ — in my keyboard, the combination that yields it is option+shift+/.

Comment: @Aaron And are you sure you’re using the Find in Project window (instead of the simple Find panel)? Regular expressions are only supported in Find in Project.

Comment: @Bavarious My xcode version is 3.2.5 64bit and I'm searching in Find in Project window itself. Can you just type the text that you can actually see in the replace box??

Comment: @Aaron That’s the same configuration as mine and it works here. When you type control+q return { in the replace box, the only visible character is { — there is no visual feedback for control+q and return.

Comment: @Bavarious Sorry for being stupid. But can you explain the steps that you have said how to actually enter the text? When I type I can see the text control return in the replace box.

Comment: @Aaron I really don’t know what else I could tell you. I’ve edited my answer to include a screenshot of the find window *after* having typed control+q return {.

Comment: @Bavarious It worked out. My problem was instead of pressing return key, I was typing return in the replace fields. Now it works. Really Thanks for your patience.....

Comment: @Bavarious Can you please explain why we have to do this instead of putting a simple expression int he replace field???

Comment: @Aaron That’s how Xcode works. It has no support for character escaping with backslashes (such as \n) in the replace box, so it uses the standard (Emacs-inherited) control+q combo to quote special keys. Note that return must be interpreted differently because it is the key equivalent of the default window button — typing return is the same as clicking Find.

Comment: Use this solution and then do ⌘+A and ctrl+I to re-indent!

Comment: This does NOT work in XCode 6.  Causes build errors. `Expected identifier`

Comment: Verified that using ctrl-q+enter works on Xcode 11 to generate multiline replacement text. Incredibly unimpressed. Xcode has an "insert pattern" "+" button to add some special patterns to the regular extension search string, but it has no equivalent for the replace pattern. I searched a long time for an answer before finding this one, because I thought it couldn't be that bad. It is. At least now it actually splits the line on the replace pattern, which gives some feedback, by why not just accept some special character sequence for this common task. How 'bout $n, if you don't want to accept /n

Answer (score 4):

Just copy an example of needed replacement string (new line or else) from code to replacement box.

Comment: Not sure if Xcode is any different, but usually you can't copy a new-line character into a single-line edit box (which is what the replacement box presumably is).

Comment: In Xcode you can, and it is IMO the quickest clean way to enter tabs, returns etc. by way of replace since Xcode will attempt to indent correctly. It's not flawless, but usually a lot quicker than constructing a RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

search for this `\s\{` and replace with `\n\{`

Your editor needs to support regular expressions in both search and replace fields.  If you can't use the \n in the replace dialog because it takes the string literally, try a option-enter followed by `{`, that works in most editors I tried.

- the `\s` is a space character (if there
  could be more spaces you can use `\s+`)

> note it has to be `\s+` instead of `\s*` as someone fixed because indeed `\s*` also matches in case there is no space.

- the `\{` needs the backslash because `{`
  needs to be escaped as it has another
  meaning in a regex
- the `\n` is for a newline

The best way however would be to reformat your code where you choose to have your `{` on a new line.  Most editors allow you to set these options.

Another way is to use a code beautifier, you can google these online and some allow to change settings like that.

Comment: And what about: `char *s = "please don't { break me!";`

Comment: you are right it's not the best way of doing this.  If you want your regex to not break this exception it can be done but it would be silly when you can simply reformat your code.

Comment: When I tried to reformat UIViewController {, it is coming as UIViewControllern{. I didn't get what you meant by "shift-enter followed by {".

Comment: @Bart Kiers - that's why we have version control

Comment: IIRC, you'll need to use Option-Return to enter a newline character in the Replace field. You can force the `{` to be line-final (barring whitespace) by searching for `\s*\{\s*$`.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: That string was asking for it. My suggestion of searching for `\s*\{\s*$` would leave it alone, though.

Comment: @Abizern, you have version control to go search-and-replace using regex? I see... :)

Comment: @Jeremy, sure, my point is that there _can_ be occasions with a `{` in it that don't need replacing. And what about `// some comment ending with a brace: {`. No matter what regex solution you throw at me: I'll break it. Really: you can't reliably do this with regex.

Comment: @bart of course you can break any freak occasion, but in this case a regexp could do just fine. And fixing those freak occasions takes far less time then actually trying to generate a regexp that includes those freak occasions

Comment: @gnur: _"...  could do just fine ..."_, true: it _could_.

Comment: @Stofke It worked when I tried with option-enter instead of shift enter.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: Yes, without syntax-awareness, it is possible to run into problems. Most text will satisfy additional constraints that make a regex solution acceptable. Also, you can use Project Find to easily review the regex matches only select the matches you wish to change before clicking the Replace button.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: The best solution: the developer tools include a syntax-aware rewriter, `tops`. Just stick `replace "{" with "\n}"` (using an actual newline in place of the `\n`) in a file named "rule" and then call `tops -scriptfile rule MyClass.m` to rewrite it appropriately. If you can figure out how to stick a newline in the command line without a problem, then you can skip the scriptfile creation step, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[\n\r]` to describe `newline`
It's a shame, I came across with that when I tap on magnifier icon next to search bar while finding something in a single file.

To see several other expressions:

1. go to a file
2. do `cmd`+`f` and open search
3. tap on the magnifier icon at the left-hand side of search field at the top
4. you can see other expressions in the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

i searched a while to find out, that you have to enable the find options for regular expressions first on the small magnifier glass in the left side of the find-input field ;)