# Regular expression to replace two blank lines with one blank line

Tags: regex, macos, cocoa

I'd like to use Xcode's find and replace by regex to remove unnecessary blank lines in my code. In other words I want to replace this:

```
NSString *helloString = @"Hello";


helloString = [helloString stringByAppendingString:@" World"];
```

With this:

```
NSString *helloString = @"Hello";

helloString = [helloString stringByAppendingString:@" World"];
```

I tried typing <kbd>control+q</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd> <kbd>control+q</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd> in the search box (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078814/regular-expression-to-replace-with-newline-in-xcode) but it didn't match anything.

What should the regex be?

Answer (score 2):

Copy 2 of the empty lines from your source, press APPLE-OPTION-F to display the searchbar and paste the two lines into the first field.
Then go the second field and enter OPTION-RETURN

Then hit the replace button on the right

Be aware that this matches only lines with the same indendation/spaces/tabs as your copied line. If you need something more flexible better use a texteditor supporting regexen.
As possible regex could be something like "\n.*\n"

Comment: Thanks. This works if there's no tabs or blank spaces in the blank lines.

Comment: Note that Xcode does support regex (see the answer I linked to in my question). I tried searching for `\n.*\n` but that returns no matches.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know regex very well. I'd just use a simple find and replace of literal strings. Select a blank line by putting your cursor on the last character of a line and pressing shift right-arrow to select the line break. Then bring up a replace dialog and paste 2 blank lines into the find field, and 1 blank line into the replace field.

Comment: Thanks. This works if there's no tabs or blank spaces in the blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode doesn't support regex matches across multiple lines, per [this mailing-list posting](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/268886-regular-expression-in-xcode-editor-newlines-whitespace.html#268888) from Apple employee #8 Chris Espinoza.

You could do a two-step process:

1. Do a regex search like this, to remove whitespace characters from otherwise empty lines:

   - Find: `^\s+$`
   - Replace: leave blank.
2. Do a textual (non-regex) search like this, to replace two empty lines with one:

   - Select two blank lines and go to Edit > Find > Use Selection For Find (Command-E)
   - Select a single blank line and go to Edit > Find > Use Selection For Replace (Command-Shift-E)

Comment: Replacing `^\s+$` with `nothing` removes *all* blank lines, so there are no blank lines left to select in the second step...

Comment: I'm not getting that result in Xcode 4.3. I guess it's possible they've changed the behavior in recent versions ...

Try changing the Find pattern to `^\s+()$` and the replace pattern to `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

For such tasks and other formatting perhaps you'd like to check [uncrustifyX](https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UncrustifyX), it's quite easy to use and extensive.